# Salto entre archivos JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en java, que se encarga de insertar la fecha automáticamente durante los 30 días de un mes, para ello divido la cantidad de archivo entre 18 y las fechas son ínter-diarias o sea que cada vez que le sumo una fecha, le estaré sumando 2 días, el problema es el siguiente, que por ejemplo, el programa lee los libros excel 1,2,3 y el 4to libro lo obvia y salta al 5to, vuelve el mismo proceso, lee el 5to, 6to, 7mo y el 8vo lo obvia, y así sucesivamente.

Estoy utilizando apache poi para el manejo de los libros excel, por aquí dejo el código a ver si alguien sabe porque me da dicho problema.

```
public ProcesaFecha(String mes, int cantidad, String celdaFecha){

    this.fecha_cadena = "";

    this.mes = mes;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.celda_fecha = new CellReference(celdaFecha);

    this.primer_archivo = true;

    this.ruta = Rutas.getRutaArchivos();



    //inicializar fechas
    this.fecha_primer_archivo = null;
    this.fecha_actual = null;

    //esto sera las veces que se ejecutara una sola fecha en en diferentes archivos
    this.fecha_por_dia = Math.floor(this.cantidad / 18); //5



    //con turno se va a comparar si es igual a fecha_por_dia si lo es pasar a la siguiente fecha
    this.turno = 1;
    getFechaPrimerArchivo();

    int indice_funcion  = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < (int)this.cantidad+1; i++){

        setFecha(indice_funcion);
        indice_funcion++;


        System.out.println(indice_funcion);
    }

}

public void setFecha(int indice){


   // System.out.println("Fecha actual " + getFechaCadena());

    //cargar archivo
     String nombre_completo = "";



    if(indice < 10){

        nombre_completo = this.ruta + mes + " 0" + Integer.toString(indice) + ".xlsx";

    }else{

        nombre_completo = this.ruta + mes + " " + Integer.toString(indice) + ".xlsx";

    }



    if(this.turno < this.fecha_por_dia){


        //SETTEAR LA NUEVA fech Y GUARDAR EL ARCHIVO
        try {

            System.out.println("Nombre del archivo " + nombre_completo);

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(nombre_completo);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


            Cell cell = null;
            XSSFRow sheetrow = sheet.getRow(this.celda_fecha.getRow());
            cell = sheetrow.getCell(this.celda_fecha.getCol());

            //cell.setCellValue(getFechaCadena());
            cell.setCellValue(this.fecha_actual);
            //System.out.println("Fecha actual en funcion " + this.fecha_actual);
            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(nombre_completo));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            

        this.turno++;

    }else{

        this.turno = 1;
        sumaDiasAfecha();

    }

}

//SE EJECUTAR PARA SUMARLE DIAS A LA FECHA LUEGO
public void sumaDiasAfecha(){

    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendario.setTime(this.fecha_actual);
    calendario.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);

    this.fecha_actual = calendario.getTime();


}





public String getFechaCadena(){//devuelve la fecha actual en texto

    String fecha_cadena = this.fecha_actual.toString();

    //Darle el formato a ala fecha
    DateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    String fecha_string = fecha.format(this.fecha_actual);


    return fecha_string;

}
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda!!

**EDITO:** **LA CANTIDAD DE ARCHIVOS TOTALES SON 75**

Comment: Opciones: O te está dando una excepción que controlas (mira si te imprime el *stacktrace*) o no se está ejecutando el código (mira el *if*).

Answer (score 0):

Para que la division sea fraccional en vez de entera, usa 18.0 en vez de 18

Una sugerencia; separa tu bucle `for` e imprime sólo los números para ver si estás obteniendo los resultados que esperas.

```
jshell> for(int i=1;i<=30;i++){System.out.printf("%g%n", Math.floor(i/18.0));}
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
1.00000
```